# ASP.NET - Web application project's generated files are conflicting with classes

Tags: c#, asp.net

We're trying to convert one of our web site projects to a web application project. Upon compilation, I get this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'ProfileCommon' exists in both 'c:\Users\zdiemer\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2cbd3103\74f6f60e\App_Code.umlhohvl.dll' and 'c:\Users\zdiemer\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\2cbd3103\74f6f60e\assembly\dl3\0a1b4881\881e27bf_c0b8d001\RatingDynamicsWebApp.DLL'
```

I've tried the following:

- Cleaning and rebuilding
- Creating a new project and copying over old files
- Renaming `App_Code` folder
- Removing `App_Code` folder
- Renaming the declared `ProfileCommon` class in the web application proejct
- Adding "`batch=false`" to the compilation section of `web.config`

For some reason, `ProfileCommon` is still being generated at compilation despite this new project being a web application project. I can see that `HttpContext.Current.Profile` is of type `ProfileCommon` when stepping through the code (renaming `ProfileCommon` to something different allows me to make it to the log in page, but upon trying to log in, I encounter the same error).

Any clues?

Comment: Sometimes, the designer files that are created in support of the converted Web Application Projects can create duplicate definitions like this arising from the web page partial classes; at least they did for me. It's tedious, but the best way to try to find them is to search the project source for ProfileCommon and see if perhaps a second declaration exists somewhere that just didn't get cleaned up.

Comment: Does it go away if you clear ASP.NET Temporary files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It was a configuration issue. We had forgotten to add the `inherits="<namespace of custom ProfileCommon>"` portion to the profile provider in `web.config`.